# Entity Frameowrk based application can't open local DB (.mdf) after being attached and detached from SSMS

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ssms

I'm developing a C# WinForm application based on Entity Framework 6.
The application create the DB if it not exists and it is working fine saving and retrieving data.
The problem is that every time I attach the DB to SSMS and detach it (checking the flag to close every connection) the application is not able to use that .mdf anymore.
It throw `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`:

> Cannot create file '' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I'm able to reproduce this behavior with these steps:

- launch application, .mdf is created;
- close application;
- attach mdf to SSMS;
- detach mdf.

Why the application can't open and use the .mdf after being attached and detached from SSMS? How can I fix this?

The only thing I noticed is that the ACL rights for .mdf and .ldf are totally changed and inheritance deactivated. I tried cloning the ACL with PowerShell but even though the clone action works correctly the application is not able to open the database.

**Solution:**
I was finally able to understand what was going on!
Trying to connect to the DB with Visual Studio Server Explorer I got this error: `...cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.`
So basically attaching the DB created with an older version of MSSQLLocalDB to SSMS 2017 upgrades the DB silently (I can't find any flag there to not upgrade).

Searching for it lead to find [this article](http://merddynsoftware.net/2018/08/24/sql-server-localdb-problems/).

I was able to solve everything by installing SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB and re-creating the LocalDB instance as showed in the article:

- install Sql Server 2017 Express LocalDB only;
- stop the instance: `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB`
- delete the instance: `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`
- create the new instance: `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`
- start the instance: `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB`

All working now.

Comment: Are you closing the connection to the db? it seems that other program is taking control of your db

Comment: @aepelman I think I'm closing it, when detaching from SSMS I check the "Drop connections" flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I was finally able to understand what was going on!
Trying to connect to the DB with Visual Studio Server Explorer I got this error: `...cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.`
So basically attaching the DB created with an older version of MSSQLLocalDB to SSMS 2017 upgrades the DB silently (I can't find any flag there to not upgrade).

Searching for it lead to find [this article](http://merddynsoftware.net/2018/08/24/sql-server-localdb-problems/).

I was able to solve everything by installing SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB and re-creating the LocalDB instance as showed in the article:

- install Sql Server 2017 Express LocalDB only;
- stop the instance: `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB`
- delete the instance: `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`
- create the new instance: `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`
- start the instance: `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB`

All working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **Initial Catalog**-Part in your ConnectionString:

```
Initial Catalog=myApp
```

You only need this attribute if the db does not exist.

Comment: I don't have "Initial Catalog" in the connection string: `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\<db_name>.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`